# How to force/indicate Outlook to reread changed registry values

Tags: .net, outlook, registry, add-in

I try to write a add-in for Outlook 2007 which is changing the reply/forward style of messages.

Basically I identified the registry keys `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences\ReplyStyle` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences\ForwardStyle`.

Those get set whenever I change those options in Outlook itself, however when I change them through code or regedit while Outlook is running, those settings don't become active till Outlook is restarted.

So my question is, how do I force/indicate Outlook to reread registry values or is there another way to change those settings through COM interop?

Comment: Can't you ask to restart outlook, like so many applications does when system settings changes ?

Comment: I want the user to be able to swtich those settings for each mail individually. Basically that was my first idea to achieve. In the meantime i figured out how to customize forms in Outlook by defining custom actions for forwarding and reply, but sill trying to figure out how to publish this form as default for every Outlook mail folder. Anyway thx for your suggestion Steve

Comment: How are you reading registry values in the first place?

Comment: In VB you can use My namespace to read/write registry with My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(). In my case that was My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences\", "ForwardStyle", Nothing)

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. I'd like to create a button that toggles the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences\PreviewMarkMessage`. And then somehow tell Outlook to refresh its preference settings. I haven't been able to find any way to change the setting via COM interop.

Comment: After doing some aditional research i would say it's simply not possible to force an update of preferences. At least ForwardStyle and ReplyStyle are read only once from registry while answering/forwarding the very first mail and remain cached from that point on. Only action that triggers rereading from registry is when opening preferences window. Also i couldn't find any hint that those application preferences are exposed by COM.