# How to manage application options/advanced options?

Tags: vba, outlook

**I need to quickly toggle *File* > *Options* > *Advanced* > *Reminders* > *Play reminder sound* setting.**

In certain meetings I need to keep Outlook running to get reminders, but don't want the reminder sound.

Currently, I manually toggle the *File* > *Options* > *Advanced* > *Reminders* > *Play reminder sound* checkmark.
This needs to be an effective single-click.
I don't want to restart Outlook as there are usually many things open.

I cannot add it to the Quick Access Toolbar.
[image]
On the left the option is present in the list of QAT commands, but not in the list of Ribbon commands, otherwise we could access it with ExecuteMso.

Three reasons:

1. The button is disabled when not in the Calendar window. That's just inelegant.
   [image]
2. When I click the button, Outlook crashes and I lose everything that wasn't saved. (Autosave isn't sufficient or functioning. That's a different problem.)
3. Understanding how to access Outlook settings with VBA opens a whole new world of possibilities.

This Microsoft article series starting at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application is about automating Outlook user tasks, like making a calendar appointment. That's not what I want, I want to manage Outlook's options.

There are some discussions about [COM add-ins as one method](https://books.google.ca/books?id=v8oZNEByTR0C&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=outlook%20vba%20advanced%20options&source=bl&ots=NkRZtTo8fs&sig=ACfU3U3C9QRtDvuGb7765hlAli5eJ5atqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj71suK9ZP3AhUYK80KHQo-CcgQ6AF6BAgkEAM#v=onepage&q=outlook%20vba%20advanced%20options&f=false), but that appears beyond me. The effort to learn COM add-ins is out of line with manual effort to achieve the desired goal.

I have some limited Outlook VBA experience but am reasonably comfortable with VBA in Word, Excel.

Answer (score 1):

To disable reminder sound you need to set the below registry key to 0.

```
Registry key: PlaySound (REG_DWORD) to be set to 0.

Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\options\Reminder
```

where 16.0 indicates the Outlook version.

Don't forget to restart Outlook to apply changes.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I forgot to put in my answer I don't want to restart Outlook, since there are often many items open and I haven't had the best luck with it restoring my full session state. The change, when performed using the File > Options sequence above, doesn't require a restart of Outlook, which leads me to believe it's also possible using some external method.

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't expose it via OOM to apply at runtime.

Comment: Well that's a drag, and it's similar to the wall I ran into thinking through Dmitry's answer. Thank you though!

Comment: Just to close off this idea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070338/how-to-force-indicate-outlook-to-reread-changed-registry-values hasn't been answered in almost 10 years. :-(

Answer (score 0):

These settings can be overridden on the per appointment basis - you can simply set `AppointmentItem`.[ReminderPlaySound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.reminderplaysound) property to false using VBA.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. However I believe that affects the individual calendar appointment item. The File > Options > Advanced > Reminders > Play reminder sound setting pictured above is for all reminder sounds (email, tasks, calendar, etc.) that Outlook initiates, and overrides any per-item sound.

Comment: Hmmm... You can set the option in registry, but Outlook won't refresh its cached value until it is restarted.

Comment: Yeah, and at that point, I might as well manually change the settings. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Simulate a button press with ExecuteMso.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso

Hover over the button where you would add it to the ribbon/QAT. See text in brackets at the end.
[Are the command codes for ExecuteMso documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610998/are-the-command-codes-for-executemso-documented)

```vb
Private Sub ExecuteMso_TextInBrackets()

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610998/are-the-command-codes-for-executemso-documented
    
    Dim oAppt As Object
    Set oAppt = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Debug.Print oAppt.subject
    
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TextInBrackets")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks niton. That's an excellent idea for anything that has a presence on the Ribbon. For reasons I don't understand, this option isn't available on the Ribbon. I can't past a picture into a comment, so I'll edit the main answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in life, the answer is a workaround. In this case, it's AutoHotkey to press the keys for me (ALT F, T, down x 9, ALT P, Enter):

```
;WIN-O toggles the Outlook alarm sound setting
#o::
SetTitleMatchMode,2 ;inexact match
WinGetActiveTitle, MyWindowTitle
If WinActive(" - email@company.com") ;Poor way to "prove" we're in Outlook
{
    ;MsgBox, We're in Outlook
    Send !ft{Down 9}
    Send !p{Enter}
}

Return
```